# How to make a Joomla Table sortable?

Tags: php, sorting, joomla, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have added **following PHP code in my Joomla webapplication.**
This will create a **table of all users from a User Group**.

***How Can I make this table sortable?***

Is there some Joomla/PHP code or plugin to order this list by Name?
Can I add a parameter to sort this by any column?

```
<?php
$teachers = JAccess::getUsersByGroup(10); //change number in the brackets

echo "<table class=\"table table-striped\">";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Street</th>";
echo "<th>Zip</th>";
echo "<th>City</th>";
echo "<th>Phone</th>";
echo "<th>Email</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($teachers as $user_id) {
    $user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);
    $profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$user->name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$profile->profile['address1']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$profile->profile['postal_code']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$profile->profile['city']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$profile->profile['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user->email."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use jquery or use a jquery plugin. You can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) or [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), they are jquery plugins that would put that feature.

Comment: DataTables is a **massive** script. I would not recommend using this along with a CMS in the slightest. There are far more adequate solutions out there

Comment: @Lodder Not sure what you consider "massive" but datatables js is about 70kb in size...

Comment: @mjayt - jquery.dataTables.js = 369kb, jquery.dataTables.min.js = 70kb.....pretty pointless when Joomla can take care of a sortable table with an API call

Comment: Agreed, but again, a 70kb minimized script is far from massive... not to mention it is most likely more powerful, and sorting happens client side instead of running back and forth to the database to query with a new order.

Answer (score 3):

e.g.
if you want it make title sortable use code similar like follwing to add table headers

```
  <?php echo JHTML::_('grid.sort', JText::_('TITLE'),  'title',
  $this->lists['order_Dir'],   $this->lists['order'] ); ?>
```

and use following function in modal to build your where clause in SQL.

```
  getUserStateFromRequest(
  $option.'filter_order_Dir', 'filter_order_Dir', 'ASC'));
```

above function will return you the ASC or DSC based upon user choice

JHTMLand JHTMLGRID are useful classes to build interactive tables

[details](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/0523-chapter-8-rendering-output.pdf) page 279

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the table to sortable on the client side, which means you will need some Javascript code. There are some jquery libraries out there that do that (like DataTables), but there also Joomla specific extensions that do exactly that, like Tabulizer for Joomla at http://www.tabulizer.com with many sorting options, plus you avoid any jQuery conflicts with other extensions. Here is a sorting demo http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support-menu/tabulizer-tips/63-sort-second-row

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [plugin Szaki Table](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/tables-a-lists/15750)  developed directly for Joomla (currently available for J! 2.5 and J! 3.x). 
Check it out, it's powerful and highly customizable tool.